# One to Many Relationship: List of many not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a simple one to many relationship mapping users to posts. Here is the relevant part of the schema:

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "password"
    t.string   "status",     :default => "User"
    t.string   "img_url"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.integer  "num_posts",  :default => 0
    t.datetime "created_at",                     :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     :null => false
  end

  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.text     "body"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "section_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

And here are the models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :bio, :email, :first_name, :img_url, :last_name, :num_posts, :password, :status, :username
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :section_id, :subject, :tag_ids, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :section
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  has_many :comments
end
```

I go into the rails console and create a new user doing User.create(attributes) and a new post doing Post.create(some attributes), assinging them to p1 and u1, respectively, then I do p1.user = u1.

Now when I do p1.user, I get a u1 object. Moreover, I can see that the user_id key is set to the key of u1 in the DB. However, when I do u1.posts, I get an empty list. How can I get a list of all of the posts that belong to a given user?

Comment: try `u1.reload.posts`

Comment: also take a look at `#inverse_of`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, when creating posts, you can create like this:

```
user.posts.create!({attributes})
```

Here in your case it could be the problem with `association caching`. Try

```
u1.reload.posts
```

Comment: The reload worked. Is association caching something I should worry about beyond the console? There are many situations where I could see updating a user and immediately wanting to see her posts. Would I need to be calling reload every time or reconfiguring my cache settings?

Comment: @user1427661 yes. It happens not only in console. see the `caching` section here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html